# Rails Devise views not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to integrate Devise into my Rails app, but am having trouble.

I want to render a User registration form in my page:

I've run `rails generate devise:views` and got:

```
  invoke  Devise::Generators::SharedViewsGenerator
  create    app/views/devise/shared
  create    app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb
  invoke  form_for
  create    app/views/devise/confirmations
  create    app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/passwords
  create    app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/registrations
  create    app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/sessions
  create    app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/unlocks
  create    app/views/devise/unlocks/new.html.erb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb
```

`land.html.haml`

```
= render 'devise/registrations/new'
```

But I get an error:

```
Missing partial devise/registrations/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * ".../app/views"
  * ".../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@startupcrawler/gems/devise-1.5.4/app/views"
```

This Doesn't work either.

```
= render 'users/registrations/new'
```

Did I configure something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To render a partial, say `users/registrations/view`, the corresponding file should be named `_new.html.erb` in the `app/views/devise/registrations` folder. However, simply doing that wouldn't make your form work in your landing page because it wouldn't have access to the resource name and Devise mappings.

Instead, I think you can follow the instructions here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app to put a form in your page. While the instructions there are for a sign in form, they should also work for a registration form.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably use the instructions you linked to

Answer (score 0):

It's = render 'devise/registrations/new'

You missed an 's'

Comment: This still doesn't work. I copy/pasted it before, it's not a spelling mistake (I'll correct mine above though)

Comment: @MichaelJohnston I don't get you. Your error log says 'devise/registration/new' which is invalid because the view is in the folder 'registrations'.

Comment: I know, it was a spelling mistake in my `haml` file.  The same error occurs when I have `'devise/registrations/new'` too

Answer (score 0):

use :template
like in haml
= render :template => 'devise/registrations/new'